# Wordpress - posts displayed in loop in post have the same the_excerpt() output

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've encountered a problem, which is quite annoying.
The thing is that I've two loops in my footer which are loading 3 last posts from two different categories. It looks like that:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('category=21&orderby=desc&numberposts=3'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <div class="footer-text-block">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent">
            <span class="footer-white-bold"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
        </a><br />
        <span class="footer-grey-thick"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('category=22&orderby=desc&numberposts=3'); 
      foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <div class="footer-text-block">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent">
            <span class="footer-white-bold"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
        </a><br />
        <span class="footer-grey-thick"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And what it outputs is that:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C58t.png

And that's the content of my post on which the footer is displayed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6ok7.png

Do you have any idea why is that happening guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here

- You need to reset your postdata after **every** custom query, that is after **every** instance of `get_posts()`. You can simply add `wp_reset_postdata();` after every end of your `foreach` loop
- you have a couple of `foreach` loops which uses the same `$post` value. You have to remember, the last value exists **outside** your `foreach` loop, and if it is not destroyed, it will influence the value in the next `foreach` loop if it has the same name. You can either rename the value to be unique for each `foreach` loop, or you can just use `unset($post)` after/outside your `foreach` loop.
- You need to set up postdata before you can make use of template tags like `the_excerpt()` or `the_title()`. Simply add `setup_postdata($post);` right after you started your `foreach` loop

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using setup_postdata($post); to make all post-related data available. You need:

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    // the rest of your code
}
```

[setup_postdata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata)